# PHP MongoDB Driver not working on centos

Tags: php, apache, mongodb, centos

I'm trying to setup the Mongo driver for PHP on CentOS server(centos-release-7-2.1511 x 86_64). These are the CentOS manuals I've referred to:  [manual 1](http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-the-mongodb-php-driver-extension-on-centos-6/) and [manual 2](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php)

Everything works fine on localhost but when I try to run it on CentOS it's not working and produces multiple errors.

While using `phpinfo()` on localhost, it shows details for Mongo but it's not working on CentOS.

Here is the PHP I'm trying to run:

```
$conn = new MongoClient();  
$database = $conn->mydb;
$collection = $database->createCollection('mycollection');
```

Comment: I edited the question to improve grammar and readability.  You should add the errors you're receiving when you run phpinfo() or the other PHP code you referred to in your question.

Comment: i have just restarted php-fpm on centos using | service php-fpm restart | and its working fine now .

Comment: you should post that as the solution to your problem and mark it as the answer (with the checkmark).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was restarting Apache service each-time whenever i was changing something in php.ini file so i have just restarted php-fpm on centos using **service php-fpm restart** and its working fine now !

It happens when you use wamp for local development which can restart all services from tray menu but on production server these service need to restart individually.